# SQL Server: Subtract only specific sums based on another column

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to subtract today's grand total from yesterday's grand total- these are held in different rows, but I can't seem to isolate the sums to subtract them to see the difference. Here's what I have so far in my table:

There are two (2) columns:

- Source `nchar(45)`
- Amount `decimal(19,3)`

So far I have tried to:

```
select
( 
    select amount as TotalToday 
    from tblDailySalesvyest
    where Source = 'grand total yest'
) ,
(
    select amount as TotalYest 
    from tblDailySalesvyest
    where Source = 'grand total today'
)
from tblDailySalesvYest
```

But I get as many rows as there are columns.
How can I isolate each total and subtract one from the other?

```
Source                                          Amount
Invoiced Today                                  NULL
Invoiced Yest                                   38009.320
Credited Today                                  NULL
Credited Yest                                   -579.920
Open Orders Today                               7913.040
Open Orders Yest                                17499.162
Grand Total Yest                                129300.562
Grand Total Today                               8650.010
```

Comment: I think you are going to need a _relation_ between records to link today's grand total to yesterday's grand total.  I would recommend changing your schema.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use conditional sum

```
 SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'grand total yest' 
                 THEN Amount
                 ELSE 0
            END) as sum_yesterday,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'grand total today' 
                 THEN Amount
                 ELSE 0
            END) as sum_today
 FROM tblDailySalesvYest
```

Comment: Thank you!! SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'grand total yest' 
                 THEN Amount
                 ELSE 0
            END) as sum_yesterday,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'grand total today' 
                 THEN Amount
                 ELSE 0
            END) as sum_today, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'grand total yest' 
                 THEN Amount
                 ELSE 0
            END) -
            SUM(CASE WHEN Source = 'grand total today' 
                 THEN Amount
                 ELSE 0
            END) as Change
            
            
 FROM tblDailySalesvYest

Answer (score 0):

First, are your sources mixed? You are referencing amount as TotalToday when the source is 'grand total YEST'.

That said, if this is what you intended, this sounds like cartesian products aren't an issue. I wouldn't use CASE since it tends to be slower than flat joins. You could either join in the FROM or have two entirely contained select statements nested within the overall select:

1.

```
SELECT
  SUM( today.amount ) AS TotalToday,
  SUM( yest.amount ) AS TotalYest
FROM
  tblDailySalesvYest AS today,
  tblDailySalesvYest AS Yest
WHERE
  today.Source = 'grand total today' AND
  yest.Source = 'grand total yest'
```

2.

```
SELECT
  ( SELECT SUM( amount ) FROM tblDailySalesvYest WHERE source = 'grand total today' ) AS TotalToday,
  ( SELECT SUM( amount ) FROM tblDailySalesvYest WHERE source = 'grand total yest' ) AS TotalYest
```